# Pairing with apps on the phone

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, deep-linking, android-contentresolver

In my application, I want to view data of some of the other android apps(health apps) which are installed on the phone. I know `ContentProvider` & `ContentResolver` classes provides this funcationality.

What if some applications do not share their data? How to pair with such apps?
For example how do I pair 'Runtastic' app with my application, pairing as in I want to open another health app(installed on phone) in my application on some button click, also want to access it's wellness related data(steps count)?

Has anybody implemented this kind of functionality?

Comment: you need the contentUri of their provider

Answer (score 2):

Android device should be rooted. Without root, you can't access these data.

Answer (score 1):

Content provide and content resolver provide data through implicit intents and you can not access data or other app installed on phone until its api is provided.